# Wix install path registry value assignment - what is wrong?

Tags: xml, wix, windows-installer

I have an WIX installer.
I try to add a registry key depending on the installation path (VS Installer easy) in this case thought it would be a piece of cake ...
This is my XML for WIX:

```
<Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="ChessBarInfoSetup" Level="1">
        <!--<ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />-->
  <ComponentRef Id='InstallRegistryComponent' />
  <ComponentRef Id='ProductComponent' />
    </Feature>
</Product>

<Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
        <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
    <Directory Id="ManufacturerFolder" Name="$(var.manufacturer)">
      <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="$(var.productName)">

        <!--<ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">-->
          <Component Id="InstallRegistryComponent" Guid="*">
            <RegistryKey Id='ChessInfoBarInstallDir' Root='HKLM' Key='Software\[Manufacturer]\[ProductName]' Action='createAndRemoveOnUninstall'>
              <RegistryValue Type='string' Name='InstallDir' Value="[INSTALLDIR]" Action="write" KeyPath="yes" />
              <!--<RegistryValue Type='integer' Name='Flag' Value='0'/>-->
            </RegistryKey>
          </Component>
          <!-- TODO: Remove the comments around this Component element and the ComponentRef below in order to add resources to this installer. -->
          <Component Id="ProductComponent" Guid="*">
            <File Source="$(var.ChessInfoTaskBar.TargetPath)" />
          </Component>
        <!--</ComponentGroup>-->

      </Directory>
    </Directory>
        </Directory> 
</Directory>
</Fragment>
```

The value is created but is always an empty string. Tried it with INSTALLLOCATION and others... What am I doing wrong (saw the Value=[INSTALLDIR] on a wix tutorial page)?

Comment: Probably a stupid question - but what is requiring you to add the installation directory into the registry?

Comment: Damien, [for example](http://wix.tramontana.co.hu/tutorial/getting-started/where-to-install). [Example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jschaffe/archive/2012/10/23/creating-wix-custom-actions-in-c-and-passing-parameters.aspx) to use it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It is empty because you are using `INSTALLDIR` instead of `INSTALLFOLDER`

```
<Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="$(var.productName)">

<RegistryValue Type='string' Name='InstallDir' Value="[INSTALLFOLDER]" />
```

That should give you the installation directory.

Comment: ... I have could sworn that I have used this option ... well THX

Comment: In my case, I've misspelled "`INSTALLLDIR`" (three "L"s instead of two). After changing it, I was able to use "`INSTALLDIR`".