# How to concat two variables at installlocation path

Tags: path, wix, installation, concatenation, wix3.7

I have some problem on WIX basic setup configuration.
I want to install my files into ProgramFiles/NameOfCompany/NameOfProduct.
I have the following configuration now:

```
<?define ProductName="ProductName" ?>
<?define Manufacturer="CompanyName"?>
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
    <Directory Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Name="$(var.ProductName)">
      <Component Id="ProductComponent" Guid="b11556a2-e066-4393-af5c-9c9210187eb2">
        <File Id='SampleAppEXE' Name='SampleApp.exe' Source='ClipboardActiveX.dll' Vital='yes' />
      </Component>
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
</Directory>
```

The problem is that i got the following error when i try to set something like this folder1/folder2 at INSTALLLOCATION directory entry:

```
The Directory/@Name attribute's value, 'folder1/folder2', is not a valid long name because it contains illegal characters.  Legal long names contain no more than 260 characters and must contain at least one non-period character.  Any character except for the follow may be used: \ ? | > < : / * ".
```

I want something like this one:

```
<?define ProductName="ProductName" ?>
<?define Manufacturer="CompanyName"?>
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
  <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
    <Directory Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Name="$(var.Manufacturer)\$(var.ProductName)">
      <Component Id="ProductComponent" Guid="b11556a2-e066-4393-af5c-9c9210187eb2">
        <File Id='SampleAppEXE' Name='SampleApp.exe' Source='ClipboardActiveX.dll' Vital='yes' />
      </Component>
    </Directory>
  </Directory>
</Directory>
```

Comment: Ok I found this option <Directory Id="ManufacturerFolder" Name="$(var.Manufacturer)"> at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13443865/wix-install-path-registry-value-assignment-what-is-wrong?rq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must use nested Directory elements for nested directories. Like this:

```
...
<Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
    <Directory Id="Manufacturer" Name="$(var.Manufacturer)">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Name="$(var.ProductName)">
...
```

Comment: Yes thanks, I think I was tried this and got another error, sorry for my oversight.